# why does my pdo like search not find the second one?

Tags: php, pdo

I am doing a search of usernames based on a text input of names like so:

```
    // find users
    $users = explode(',', $_POST['to']);

    $user_id_list = array();

    print_r($users);

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $db->sqlquery("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE ?", array("%$user%"));
        $user_id = $db->fetch();
        $user_id_list[] = $user_id['user_id'];
    }

    print_r($user_id_list);
```

But it only ever seems to find the first one and not the second? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns only the next row of the result data. You can iterate through `$db->fetchAll()` or use `while (($row = $db->fetch()) !== false)` to access all the returned rows.

Comment: Inside a loop it constantly runs i found the error anyway, the usernames had a white space in them.